# Macro to open, recode and stack several .csv files in SPSS

Tags: loops, macros, spss

I am trying to code a macro that:

1. Import the columns `year`, `month`, `id`, `value` and `motive` from several .csv sequential files to SPSS. The files are named like: `DATA_JAN_2010`,  `DATA_FEB_2010` [...],  until `DATA_DEC_2019`. These are the first variables of the csv files (the code I am using to import this variables is provided in the end).
2. Alter type of columns `id` to `(a11)`, `motive` to `(a32)`, if necessary (needed to stack all files).
3. Stack all these datasets in a new dataset named: `DATA_2010_2019`.

For now, what I am doing is to import each file separately, stacking and saving two by two. But this is so repetitive and irrational from the efficiency standpoint. Moreover, if in the future I need to import additional variables, I would need to rewrite all the code for each file. That is why I believe that a loop or a macro would be the smartest way of dealing with this repetitive codes. Any help is really appreciated.

A sample of my code so far:

```
GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="C:\Users\luizz\DATA\DATA_JAN_2010.csv"
  /ENCODING='Locale'
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=";"
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=2
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
  YEAR F4.0
  MONTH F1.0
  ID A11
  VALUE F4.0
  MOTIVE A8.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME JAN_2010 WINDOW=FRONT.

ALTER TYPE MOTIVE (a32).

GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="C:\Users\luizz\DATA\DATA_FEB_2010.csv"
  /ENCODING='Locale'
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=";"
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=2
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
  YEAR F4.0
  MONTH F1.0
  ID A11
  VALUE F4.0
  MOTIVE A8.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME FEB_2010 WINDOW=FRONT.

DATASET ACTIVATE FEB_2010.
ALTER TYPE MOTIVE (a32).

DATASET ACTIVATE JAN_2010.
ADD FILES /FILE=*
  /FILE='FEB_2010'.
EXECUTE.

SAVE OUTFILE='C:\Users\luizz\DATA\DATA_JAN_FEV_2010.sav'
  /COMPRESSED.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the parameters for all the files are the same, you can use a macro like this:

```
define !getfiles ()
!do !yr=2010 !to 2019
!do !mn !in("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC")
GET DATA 
  /TYPE=TXT /FILE=!concat('"C:\Users\luizz\DATA\DATA_', !mn, '_', !yr, '.csv"')
  /ENCODING='Locale'   /DELCASE=LINE   /DELIMITERS=";"   /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=2   /IMPORTCASE=ALL   /VARIABLES= 
  YEAR F4.0
  MONTH F1.0
  ID A11
  VALUE F4.0
  MOTIVE A8.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
ALTER TYPE id (a11) MOTIVE (a32).
dataset name tmp.
dataset activate gen.
add files /file=* /file=tmp.
exe.
!doend !doend
!enddefine.
```

The macro as defined will read each of the files and add it to a main file. Before we call the macro we will create the main file:

```
data list list/YEAR (F4)  MONTH (F1) ID (A11) VALUE (F4) MOTIVE (A8).
begin data
end data.
exe.
dataset name gen.
* now we can call the macro.
!getfiles .
* now the data is all combined and we can save it.
SAVE OUTFILE='C:\Users\luizz\DATA\DATA_JAN_FEV_2010.sav'  /COMPRESSED.
```

NOTE: I used your code from the original post in the macro. Please make sure all the definitions are right.

Comment: Hi @eli-k, thank you very much for your code! I was having an error while running it.  "Unknown dataset gen. Execution of this command stops." . But then I thought for a while and I figured it out. You forgot to write "dataset name gen." after you created the main file. Then it ran smoothly!!! Thanks!!! I had no idea on how to write a macro on SPSS.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the correction. Glad it helps!